# If $g \circ f=g$, prove that $g$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ be a monotonic function so that $|f(x) - f(y) | <|x-y|$, $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R} $, $x\neq y$. If $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is a continuous function and $g \circ f=g$, prove that $g$ is constant.
This problem also previously asked to prove that $f$ has a unique fixed point and I could show this by proving that $f$ is continuous and considering the function $h(x) =f(x) - x$. Yet, I don't know how to use this to prove that $g$ is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote by $c$ the fixed point of $f$.

Let $a \in \mathbb R$ be arbitrary. Then 
$$g(a)=g(f(a))=g(f^2(a))=....=g(f^n(a))=...$$

The sequence $x_n =f^n(a)$ converges to the fixed point $c$ of $f$. Therefore by continuity of $g$

$$g(a)=g(x_n) \to g(c)$$

This shows that $g(a)=g(c)$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Wow, nice proof! Could you explain to me why  $x_n$ converges to $c$?

Comment: @MathEnthusiast Try Googling the "Banach fixed point theorem" (or the "contraction mapping principle").

Comment: @MathEnthusiast Didn't you prove it in part 1? If not, First show that there exists some $D<1$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| <D |x-y|$ for all $x,y  \in \mathbb R$... Then $$|x_{n+1}-c|=|f(x_n)-f(c)| \leq D |x_n -c|$$ and hence, by induction $$|x_{n}-c| < D^{n-1} |x_1-c|$$ Since $D<1$, it follows immediately that $x_n \to c$.

Comment: @Xander Henderson You are right, $f$ is a contraction from the initial constraint. Yet, I don't know how the fact that $f$ is monotonous helps.

Comment: @N. S. Now I understand, I could have used Banach's fixed point theorem directly. However, this doesn't use the fact that $f$ is monotonous. Is that condition redundant?

Comment: @MathEnthusiast I think you need monotonicity and range inside $[0,1]$ to deduce the inequality $$|f(x)-f(y)| <D |x-y|$$ for some $D <1$.... Are you sure you didn't use monotonicity in Part 1?

Comment: @MathEnthusiast And no, Banach fixed point cannot be used directly... To use it , you need to prove that such $D<1$ exists!

Comment: @N. S. No need for montony in part 1. Just take the limit as $x \to y $ to conclude that $f$ is continuous. Let $h(x) =f(x) - x$. $h(0)$ and $h(1)$ have different signs(or one of them is $0$) so from Bolzano's theorem $\exists x_0 \in [0,1]$ with $h(x_0)=0$. The uniqueness is easilly proved by contradiction.

Comment: @N. S. Yes, I have just realised that.